# optimizing update statements

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to optimize sql code. I would like to know if there is an alternate way of writing these statements, because it seems take a good deal of time to complete.

```
Update #TMP---updates  webid when its null in tmp table
Set #TMP.webid_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.webid is null

Update #TMP---updates  PID when its null in tmp table
Set #TMP.PID_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.Pid is null

Update #TMP---Shifts multiple fob situations into storewide
Set #TMP.GMM ='Storewide'
Where  #TMP.gmm like '%, %';

Update #TMP-----Shifts marketing into multiple fob situation
Set #TMP.GMM ='Storewide'
Where  #TMP.gmm like 'Marketing%'


Update #TMP
Set #TMP.OVERALL_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.webid is null
```

This does have over 22,000 entries.

Comment: Optimizing this single update seems like a small thing. If the process is running slowly, are you sure the issue isn't being called too frequently? It needs to scan an entire table every time this is run, for each query. The problem may be that you need to change other parts of the process.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not positive that this will be faster as it would depend on the data, but a single update statement might perform best.

```
Update #TMP
Set #TMP.webid_Val=
        CASE
            WHEN #TMP.webid is null THEN 'NOT COMPLIANT'
            ELSE #TMP.webid_Val
        END
     ,#TMP.PID_Val=
        CASE
            WHEN #TMP.Pid is null THEN 'NOT COMPLIANT'
            ELSE #TMP.PID_Val
        END
     ,#TMP.GMM=
        CASE
            WHEN (#TMP.GMM like '%, %' OR #TMP.gmm like 'Marketing%') THEN 'Storewide'
            ELSE #TMP.GMM
        END
    ,#TMP.OVERALL_Val=
        CASE
            WHEN (#TMP.webid is null) THEN 'NOT COMPLIANT'
            ELSE #TMP.OVERALL_Val
        END
WHERE #TMP.webid is null
OR #TMP.Pid is null
OR #TMP.gmm like '%, %'
OR #TMP.gmm like 'Marketing%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The very first piece I see is that you can combine these two update statements:

```
Update #TMP---updates  webid when its null in tmp table
Set #TMP.webid_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.webid is null

Update #TMP
Set #TMP.OVERALL_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.webid is null
```

Into:

```
Update #TMP---updates  webid when its null in tmp table
Set #TMP.webid_Val='NOT COMPLIANT',
    #TMP.OVERALL_Val='NOT COMPLIANT'
Where  #TMP.webid is null
```

You could combine the two GMM updates into the following:

```
Update #TMP---Shifts multiple fob situations into storewide
Set #TMP.GMM ='Storewide'
Where  LEFT(#TMP.gmm, 9) = 'Marketing'
OR #TMP.gmm like '%, %';
```

Performing the `LEFT` as opposed to the `LIKE` matching should be a little bit more performant (note: not sure about that, you would have to test it to verify).